# Selector with dynamic argument not memoized

Tags: redux, reselect

I'm trying to get Reselect to memoize my selector called with a dynamic argument

My selector:

```js
import { createSelector, defaultMemoize } from 'reselect'

const allStatesSelector = store => store.state.states

export const getAllStates = createSelector(
  allStatesSelector,
  states => defaultMemoize(night => {
    console.log('getAllStates called with night:', night)
    const availableStates = night ? nightStates : dayStates
    return states.filter(state => availableStates.includes(state.id))
  }),
)
```

I'm calling it like so:

```js
states: getAllStates(store)(props.night)
```

The selector is called 1800 times instead of just 2 (considering night can only be true or false).

What did I miss?

Comment: Are "nightStates" and "dayState" constants? Is there a reason why you explicitly use "defaultMemoize"?